# Accessing IRequestContext on a plugin on ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to create a plugin based on ServiceStack [IPlugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) interface that can measure the time elapsed on the operations and publish it to a dashboard. The code itself would be quite simple and I tried to do it based on some concepts on the [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger).

This logger uses a [StopWatch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/730f07763747520805aee728d725bbee3d2da8cb/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/ServiceRunner.cs#L62) that is added inside the default ServiceRunner class, but it only does it when the Request Logger is configured.

I already have a custom ServiceRunner and the StopWatch is being initialized there but using this approach isn't optimal since the plugin is not self-contained.

My biggest issue now is that I apparently can't access the IRequestContext. Is there any way an plugin can access this context or any other way to measure the time to run the requests inside a simple plugin, not depending on a ServiceRunner?

Thanks!

Comment: can you update the question with your Iplugin impl?

Answer (score 1):

Store the start time on the request in a RequestFilter and then in a ResponseFilter calculate the time using the current time minus the start time?

This can be done in a plugin too.

Here's some pseudo code...

```
appHost.RequestFilters.Add( ( req, res, obj ) =>
    {
        if(!req.Items.ContainsKey( "begin-time" ) )
            req.Items.Add( "begin-time", DateTime.Now );
        else
            req.Items[ "begin-time" ] = DateTime.Now;
    }
);

appHost.ResponseFilters.Add( ( req, res, i ) =>
    {
        var beginTime = (DateTime)req.Items[ "begin-time" ];

        var elapsed = DateTime.Now - beginTime;
    }
);
```